# Why are codeblocks displaying errors?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

**Code:**

```
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    map<int, int> mp1, mp2; 
    mp1.insert({ 1, 2 }); 
    cout << "The max size of mp1 is " << mp1.max_size(); 
    cout << "\nThe max size of mp2 is " << mp2.max_size(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

**Everytime I run map, error message will say**... 
[image]

*For the above error, I am changing the setting of codeblocks*...**Setting >GNU GCC Compiler>Compiler flags>Have g++ follow the C++ 11 ISO C++ language standard[-std=c++11]**
*But this time also showing the same* **error**.

**what should I do??**

Comment: You have included several .cpp files in the project, each of which defines `main` function. There should only be one `main` in the program. If you want to build several applications, set up a separate project for each.

Comment: Looks like codeblocks is even telling you the name of the other file to the left of where it says 'first defined here'

Comment: It seems you're building a project named *Debug in lterators*. You should create a new project where only this file is present. Assuming you're a beginner, you can just create a new *.cpp* file on your Desktop and open it with Code::Blocks. Copy the content and paste it there. Then just press F9. A console window showing your output shall open thereafter.